# copying a string to a pointer in x86 assembly with At&t syntax

Tags: string, pointers, assembly, char, att

So, another function calls this one and gives it a char*. This function is supposed to create a string and replace the value of the char* with that of the string.

```
.text
.global func
.LC0:
    .string "hereisasamplemessage\0"
func:

    movl  $.LC0,4(%eax)

    ret
```

What it actually does is corrupts the char. I get a fuzzy square as output. If I also tried moving asci values into eax like this:

```
movl $101,4(%eax)
movl $101,8(%eax)
```

It worked for the first asci value, then I get a fuzzy square as the following character.

Really, I'm not completely clear on how strings work in assembly. Is LC0 a reserved variable stored in another register or is it a register?

Comment: Note that characters are 1 byte each, but you use `long` instructions and offsets, so you are writing 4 bytes every time. Thus, you get 1 correct char followed by 3 zeroes, which normally signal end of string, but depending on your output method you might see them as _fuzzy squares_. `.LC0` is just a label for that string sample.